# Vue how to concat two variable and bind to a tag's attribute

Tags: vue.js

I want to use variable b as a property name in another variable a to perform v-bind.

```html
<input type="text" :name="a" :id="b" :value="a.b">
```

example:

```js
b='first';
a.first=123;
```

I's not right to use such as 'a.b', how can I concat these two variables to one string and use it to bind value?
With great thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets to access the dynamic property on `a`:

```html
<input type="text" :name="a" :id="b" :value="a[b]">
```

Comment: GREAT! It really does ! Thank you very much!